# Parametric solutions to $(4/3)b^2c^2+(4/3)a^2d^2-(1/3)a^2c^2-(4/3)b^2d^2=\square$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ and $d$ be rational.Find a rational parametric solutions for $a,b,c$ and $d$ so that 
$$(4/3)b^2c^2+(4/3)a^2d^2-(1/3)a^2c^2-(4/3)b^2d^2=\square.$$

Answer (score 2):

For the equation:

$$4c^2b^2+4d^2a^2-c^2a^2-4d^2b^2=3t^2$$

Can specify any number :  $d,c$ . Then decisions will be.

$$a=(d^2-c^2)p^2+3s^2$$

$$b=(d^2-c^2)p^2-3cps-3s^2$$

$$t=c(d^2-c^2)p^2+4(d^2-c^2)ps-3cs^2$$

$p,s$ - any integer asked us.

Comment: Thank you this parametrization is very nice. But could you please how you get a,b and t?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as

$$4b^2(c^2-d^2) = a^2(4d^2-c^2) = a^2(4d^2-4c_0^2)$$

where $c_0 = c/2$. Then 
$$b^2(c^2-d^2) = a^2(d^2-c_0^2)$$

We can assign: $b^2 = d^2-c_0^2$ and $4d^2-c^2 = a^2$.

For the first equation we use the famous Pythagorean triple: $b = 3, d = 5, c_0 = 4 \rightarrow c = 8$.
Then it brings us to the last variable: $a = 6$.

Comment: Thank you. But what is the final parametrization for a,b,c,d. What I saw only was a numerical example.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to make that polynomial a square. Let,

$$P = (4/3)b^2c^2+(4/3)a^2d^2-(1/3)a^2c^2-(4/3)b^2d^2$$

Then,

$$P = (a d)^2,\quad \text{if}\, a = 2b\tag{1}$$

and all other variables are free. Similarly,

$$P = (b c)^2,\quad \text{if}\, c = 2d\tag{2}$$

$$P = (2b d)^2,\quad \text{if}\, a = 2b,\, \text{or}\, c = 2d\tag{3}$$

where the last one is equivalent to *restrest's* solution. (Note that $a = 6$ and $b = 3$ is $a=2b$.)

Are there any other conditions on $P$?